# Itertools return value NOT used in combinations

Tags: python

I am using `for num in combinations(nums[0], number):` to return all combinations of numbers in a list, where `num = len(nums[0])-1`.

What I would like to do is return, as a separate variable, the value of the list item that is not used in each combination, so for example if `nums[1,2,3]` then I would want it to return:

```
[1,2],[3]   
[1,3],[2]  
[2,3],[1]
```

Please tell me if this is unclear. I feel like this is probably some basic python fundamentals but I can't figure out how to do it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are the values in your list unique, or could there be duplicates?

Comment: I didn't even think about that, thank you. There could definitely be duplicates, but say for example if there are 3 '2's' and 2 are included in a combination, I would still want it to return the 3rd as the unused value.

Comment: Are you sure you want both `[1,2],[3]` and `[2,1],[3]` in your output? If so you need permutations, not combinations; but it could just be a typo.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3 , I don't think I actually do. Is combinations the correct method here?

Comment: Combinations is correct if you don't want those two that are the same (but in different orders). I've edited the output in your question to how I think it should be; if that's wrong, you can edit it again.

Comment: What is the context for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your list can have duplicates:

```
from itertools import combinations

nums = [1, 2, 3, 3]

# get combinations of all possible lengths
combos = []
for n in range(len(nums)):
    combos += combinations(nums, n)

# create the pairs you want, but with all nums
combo_pairs = [(combo, list(nums)) for combo in combos]
# remove the nums that are in the combination for each pair
for combo, combo_nums in combo_pairs:
    for n in combo:
        combo_nums.remove(n)

print(combo_pairs)
```

Note: this will cause duplicates for duplicate values (one for the one three, one for the other). You can get rid of those like this:

```
combo_pairs = list(set([(combo, tuple(combo_nums)) for combo, combo_nums in combo_pairs]))
```

That turns the nums in the pair into a tuple, since a tuple is hashable, but a list isn't. You can always convert back to a list, if you need to of course.

If you're only interested in combinations that have a length that's one less than the original, you can do this:

```
from itertools import combinations

nums = [1, 2, 3, 3]

# get combinations of correct length
combos = combinations(nums, len(nums)-1)

# create the pairs you want, but with all nums
combo_pairs = [(combo, list(nums)) for combo in combos]
# remove the nums that are in the combination for each pair
for combo, combo_nums in combo_pairs:
    for n in combo:
        combo_nums.remove(n)

print(combo_pairs)
```

But in that case, you may as well:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 3]
combos = [(nums[:n] + nums[n+1:], [nums[n]]) for n in range(len(nums))]
```

Comment: For `nums = [1, 2, 1]`, if the second `1` is the combination, I'd expect the remainder to be `[1, 2]`. But you make it `[2, 1]`. Also, you say "all possible lengths" but don't include `n == len(nums)`. If you did, I think you could just use `zip(combos, combos[::-1])` (but I'm too sleepy to prove it :-).

Answer (score 0):

Since the rest of the combination is uniquely determined by which element is "left out", you don't really need itertools for this.

```py
def combinations_leaving_one_out(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    prev_x = None
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x != prev_x:
            yield tuple(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]), x
        prev_x = x
```

Example:

```py
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]
>>> for comb, left_out in combinations_leaving_one_out(lst):
...     print(comb, left_out)
... 
(1, 2, 2, 3, 4) 1
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4) 2
(1, 1, 2, 2, 4) 3
(1, 1, 2, 2, 3) 4
```

Comment: Your solution only works for the leaving out one element case though - I got the sense that this was just an example, but the required solution needs to work for any combination?

Comment: @Grismar Well, the title says *"value NOT used"* in the singular, the first paragraph says `num = len(nums[0])-1`, and the second paragraph says *"the list item that is not used"* in the singular again. I think that's fairly clear, though of course other people will likely find this question while looking for a solution to the general case.

Comment: I agree sufficiently to have added an extra section to my answer, but I also agree that a general solution is probably more useful to many people that end up here.